# Proving the Fact of balanced edge binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, divide-and-conquer

Is it possible to prove the following fact?

Any n-node binary tree T has a balanced edge: an edge whose removal will separate T into two binary trees, each having a most roundingUP[(2n-1)/3] nodes.?

and how does binary tree having a balanced edge look like??

Comment: I've never heard this before, but after a few moments consideration, It seems like an interesting problem.  I don't fully understand the (2n-1)/3 limit though.  I feel like I need to think on this much more.

Comment: Wait, what's an n-node binary tree?  I know a n-ary tree, and I know binary trees, not sure about an n-node binary tree.

Comment: I feel like the limit can be tightened to `~UP[n/2+log(n)]`, which makes me think there's an edge case I'm missing.

Comment: binary tree with n number of nodes.

Comment: how does binary tree having a balanced edge look like?? is it like one that its subtrees having equal number of edges???

Comment: @bbbBBB Your fact says that _all_ binary trees have a balanced edge.  I can't show you what makes them different about those trees, because there are no different trees.  What's unique is the _edge_.

Comment: @Mooing Duck I think this proof is done by using relationship between nodes and edges... like n # of internal nodes = n-1  # of internal edges..